# remove frame around text in geom_label_repel

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to remove the black frame around the text of my `geom_label_repel` . Any solution to this, tried all the below, but not able to remove the small black frame,

```
geom_label_repel(data = data,
                 aes(x = 0, 
                 y = value, 
                 label = absolute),
                 size = 3,
                 fontface = "bold",force = 0,fill="white",box.padding = 0,
                 label.padding = 0,point.padding = 0,label.r = 0,label.size = 0,colour="black")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `geom_text_repel()` instead?

Comment: worked fine! thx